# Inject an unknown value at registration time with Unity

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, unity-container

Here the Unity registration

```
public static class UnityConfig
{
    public static void RegisterComponents()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<ITestService,TestService>(new InjectionConstructor("XXXXX"));
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
    }
}
```

Here the webApi controller

```
[MyFilter]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    private ITestService _testService;
    public EmployeeController(ITestService testService)
    {
        _testService = testService;
    }
}
```

My test class

```
public interface ITestService
{
    string GetText();
}
public class TestService : ITestService
{
    private string _mystring;
    public TestService(string mystring)
    {
        _mystring = mystring;
    }
    public string GetText()
    {
        return _mystring;
    }
}
```

The problem : The value to inject in the constructor (hard coded here "XXXXX")is know only in `[MyFilter]` not before, not at registration time. Is it possible to inject a value coming from the attribute ?

Thanks,

Update1:
The workaround I used is save the value "XXXXX" in session working but not very clean.

```
public class MyFilter: AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{
        public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            try
            {

                HttpContext.Current.Session["MyData"] = "XXXXX";
                    return;

                HandleUnauthorized(actionContext);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }

    private void HandleUnauthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code for `MyFilter`. Where is the value `XXXXX` configured in your filter??

Comment: you can use a custom type converter and pick the value from your config for example.

Comment: you can inject value of `mystring` while resolving `ITestService`

Comment: You could register a factory instead, and pass the value when the factory creates your actual `ITestService`. It could also pass in its own type so the factory gets the value from a custom attribute on that type.

Answer (score 0):

Inject value in resolve method:

```
container.RegisterType<ITestService,TestService>();
...
var service = container.Resolve<ITestService>(new ParameterOverride(@"mystring", new InjectionParameter(typeof(string), "XXXXX")));
```

Comment: That's not explain how and where I send the right value

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment above, this example shows a way of storing the filter value in an attribute and recovering it to pass it into the `TestService`:

This assumes that each `TestController` will use the same filter (here `abc`), and that each `OtherTestController` will use the same other filter (like, `def` ?). That is, the filter attached to the type not the instance.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        var unityContainer = new UnityContainer();

        unityContainer.RegisterType<ITestServiceFactory, TestServiceFactory>();

        var theController = unityContainer.Resolve<TestController>();

        // theController._testService.FilterString is "abc"
    }
}

[MyFilter("abc")]
public class TestController
{
    private ITestService _testService;
    public TestController( ITestServiceFactory testServiceFactory )
    {
        _testService = testServiceFactory.CreateTestService(this);
    }
}

public class MyFilterAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string FilterString
    {
        get;
    }

    public MyFilterAttribute( string filterString )
    {
        FilterString = filterString;
    }
}

public interface ITestServiceFactory
{
    ITestService CreateTestService( object owner );
}

public interface ITestService
{
    string GetText();
}

internal class TestServiceFactory : ITestServiceFactory
{
    public ITestService CreateTestService( object owner )
    {
        return new TestService( ((MyFilterAttribute)owner.GetType().GetCustomAttribute( typeof( MyFilterAttribute ) )).FilterString );
    }
}

internal class TestService : ITestService
{
    public TestService( string mystring )
    {
        _mystring = mystring;
    }
    public string GetText()
    {
        return _mystring;
    }

    private readonly string _mystring;
}
```

If you don't insist on the attribute, you can simplify this and set the filter in `TestController`'s constructor directly:

```
    public TestController( ITestServiceFactory testServiceFactory )
    {
        _testService = testServiceFactory.CreateTestService("abc");
    }
```